# Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, filenotfoundexception, build-tools

I have a weird situation. These are the dependencies in my app's build.gradle:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient"
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.imangazalievm:quickmenu:0.1.0'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
compile 'com.diegocarloslima:fgelv:0.1.+@aar'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
compile files('libs/mobile.connect-android-1.7.6.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
```

[image] This is my libs folder. I use android studio 2.3.3. Question is when I run the same program on android studio 2.0 Beta 6 with build tools 25 instead of 26 it works well. How is it possible that without mobile connect jar it runs on one machine and not on other?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also copy and paste the error message here.

Comment: Clean and build again and see if it error persists

Comment: Try invalidate caches / Restart

Comment: @Reena I don't think you got my question. I don't have that jar in my app/lib . Similarly neither does my colleague who ran the project on another machine. How is it that it works for him not for me?

Comment: @Adnan I tried that. Doesn't work

Comment: Sometimes instant run cause this issue. That's why I suggested you to clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the jar(**mobile.connect-android-1.7.6.jar**) from the java build path and add again. Make sure that you have cleaned the project before running it.